# How find the $(x^2_{1}+x_{1}x_{2}+x^2_{2})(x^2_{2}+x_{2}x_{3}+x^3_{3})(x^2_{3}+x_{3}x_{1}+x^2_{1})$

Tags: calculus

Let  $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ be the roots of the equation
$$4x^3-6x^2+7x-8=0.$$
Find this value:
$$(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)(x_2^2+x_2x_3+x_3^3)(x_3^2+x_3x_1+x_1^2)$$

My try:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=\frac 3 2$$
$$x_1 x_2+x_2 x_3+x_1 x_3=\frac 7 4$$
$$x_1 x_2 x_3=2$$

Now I have
$$x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2=(x_1+x_2)^2-x_1x_2=(\frac 3 2-x_3)^2-\frac 2 {x_3}.$$

But this is very ugly, and I think this problem should have a cleaner solution. Thanks.

Comment: Does your first sentence mean "Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the roots of the equation $4x^3 - 6x^2 + 7x - 8 = 0$."?  (Also, is this question really about calculus)?

Comment: may be your question is $(x^2_{1}+x_{1}x_{2}+x^2_{2})(x^2_{2}+x_{2}x_{3}+x^2_{3})(x^2_{3}+x_{3}x_{1}+x^2_{1})$

Comment: Yes,@AdrianRatnapala,It's my mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice
$$
x_1^2 + x_1x_2 + x_2^2 = \frac{x_1^3 - x_2^3}{x_1 - x_2}
= \frac{(6x_1^2 -7x_1 + 8)-(6x_2^2 -7x_2 + 8)}{4(x_1-x_2)}\\
= \frac{6(x_1+x_2)-7}{4} = \frac{6(\frac{3}{2} - x_3) - 7}{4}
= \frac{1-3x_3}{2} = \frac32(\frac13 - x_3)
$$
and similar expression holds for $x_2^2 + x_2x_3 + x_3^2$ and $x_3^2 + x_3x_1 + x_1^2$.
The expression we want is equal to

$$\begin{align}
  & \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3(\frac13 - x_1)(\frac13 - x_2)(\frac13 - x_3)\\
= & \frac14 \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3\left[4\left(\frac13\right)^3 - 6\left(\frac13\right)^2 + 7\left(\frac13\right) - 8\right]\\
= & -\frac{167}{32}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that we need to calculate $$(x^2_1+x_1x_2+x^2_2)(x^2_2+x_2x_3+x^2_3)(x^2_3+x_3x_1+x^2_1)$$

Let $\displaystyle x^2_1+x_1x_2+x^2_2=y_3,x^2_2+x_2x_3+x^2_3=y_1, x^2_3+x_3x_1+x^2_1=y_2$

So, $\displaystyle y_3=x^2_1+x_1x_2+x^2_2=(x_1+x_2)^2-x_1x_2$
$=\left(\frac32-x_3\right)^2-\frac2{x_3}$ as $x_1+x_2+x_3=\frac32$ and  $x_1 x_2 x_3=2$

On re-arrangement we have,  $\displaystyle 4x_3^3-12x_3^2+x_3(9-4y_3)-8=0\ \ \ \  (1)$

Again as $x_3$ is a root of the given equation, $4x_3^3-6x_3^2+7x_3-8=0\ \ \ \ (2)$

$(2)-(1)\implies 6x_3^2+x_3\{7-(9-4y_3)\}=0\iff 2x_3(3x_3+2y_3-1)=0$

As $0$ does not satisfy the given equation $x_3\ne0$
$\displaystyle \implies 3x_3+2y_3-1=0\iff x_3=\frac{1-2y_3}3$

Putting the value of $x_3$ in $(2)$ we get,

$$4\left(\frac{1-2y_3}3\right)^3-6\left(\frac{1-2y_3}3\right)^2+7\left(\frac{1-2y_3}3\right)-8=0$$

On re-arrangement we have,

$\displaystyle  4(2y_3)^3+(\cdots)y_3^2+(\cdots)y_3+3^3\cdot8-3^3\cdot7+3\cdot6-4=0$

$\displaystyle \implies 32y_3^3+(\cdots)y_3^2+(\cdots)y_3+167=0\ \ \ \ (3)$

As the values of $y_1,y_2,y_3$ are symmetric, we shall reach at the same equation $(3)$ if we start with $y_1$ or $y_2$

$\displaystyle \implies y_1,y_2,y_3$ are the roots equation $(3)$

Using [Vieta's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), $\displaystyle y_1y_2y_3=-\frac{167}{32}$

Comment: Hello,I don't understand your methods.

Comment: @nanchangjian, please find the edited version